# Difference between 必须得 and 一定要 in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

For example, if I want to say, "for this class you gotta have a cup of coffee (to stay awake)", should I say 你一定要有咖啡 or 你必须的有咖啡? Note that in this context, I am not demanding that the person buy coffee, but rather stating that it's something I think is very important. Or maybe this type of expression is not important in Chinese, and I should just say, "上这个课时，咖啡很重要".

Comment: Your post titled: "Difference between 必须得 and 一定要？" and you accepted an answer that didn't address the issue at all. Instead, it just provided a rewrite. Why? Do you want to know the difference between 必须要有 and 一定要有 or not?

Comment: Because the accepted answer expressed my meaning in a better way. Context is important. I suggested options A and B, but the correct answer was C. I didn't know when I was asking the question.

Comment: Although anything can be translated, the question is: is that how a Chinese person would express that sentiment? A nation of tea-drinkers won't automatically refer to coffee. I think a more suitable phrase is: 沉闷的课堂让人昏昏欲睡。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I clearly understand the meaning of your question. I think for your purpose, a better way to say is that "上这门课你最好准备一杯咖啡"。

Comment: I think that's more appropriate. In English, it's a little sarcastic. Like "if you don't have coffee, you will definitely fall asleep". But in Chinese, sarcasm doesn't exist, so it has to be expressed more literally.

Comment: I think it might be a matter of cultural differences. In Chinese, there may be a tendency to soften and explain things in a more gentle and indirect way. I used a suggestive tone to soften the sentence. If I were to say this sentence in English myself, I might also say ‘for this class you’d better have a cup of coffee (to stay awake)’, which might not sound as authentic to you. I ask new bing to translate this sentence to Chinese, and it translate it as '对于这门课程，你需要一杯咖啡（来保持清醒）'. It use 'Need' instead of 'gotta' to soften the sentence.

Comment: @salamander I just want to let you know, sarcasm absolutely does exist in Chinese.  Like most things it is not exactly the same as the english version, however I honestly have no idea how someone could tell you it doesn't exist--its very prevalent.

Comment: @zagrycha, it seems to have failed anytime I have tried it. People take things literally. Maybe you can offer some examples instead of letting me take your word for it.

Comment: @salamander What is your level in chinese? It is not chinese specific,but chinese people will often assume a literal meaning to what someone says if they are beginning to learn the language etc.  An example of sarcasm in chinese could be: a coworker is standing on a fire escape smoking, and I comment "I see the project you are so busy with is going nicely."

Comment: @salamander Another example is my water heater is broken, and when asking whats wrong I am told the water heater is broken, I respond "oh, I never would have known that". Both these would be completely understood as sarcasm in chinese if the person was expecting it as a possibility.  If I am struggling to remember how to say water heater they probably will take my comment literally and add to my anger haha.

Comment: @zagrycha Sorry, I didn’t notice that he might have expected to express sarcasm. But indeed, you are right, sarcasm does exist in Chinese. Personally, I feel that there is no clear distinction for sarcasm in Chinese and it is difficult to judge. The same sentence spoken in different tones can have different meanings, and inappropriate nonsense or rhetorical questions may also be possible depending on the specific situation. It is difficult to accurately tell him how to be sarcastic, this is difficult.

Comment: @zagrycha And now on the Chinese Internet due to the absence of tone and weakened scenarios, it is difficult to judge whether some people are sincere statements or sarcasm, even Chinese people find it difficult to do so.

Comment: @ENJOU yes, whether chinese, english, or another language, sarcasm is always hard to grasp and describe clearly even when it definitely exists.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, they are the same and are interchangeable. Although 必须得 is slightly stronger than 一定要，I don't think such slight difference makes any different meaning, especially in speaking language.